# Export Artboards as Multiple, Multi-Page PDFs in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, export, artboard, plugin

I know that it is possible to export individual artboards all as separate PDFs in Illustrator, but I need to group some of the artboards together and I can't find a good solution.

At the moment, I'm exporting all of them and then manually combining each one using Preview (mac) which takes forever.

An example of what I mean: I have artboards 1-24, I want 12 PDFs, artboard 1-2 is PDF#1, artboard 3-4 is PDF#2, artboard 5-6 is PDF#3 and so on.

Is there a quick workaround or plugin that can help me do this efficiently?

Comment: This is relatively straightfoward to do on windows, as you can just print pdf with adobe pdf, using ranges. But i dont think thats a option on mac so you need to do the extra step of merging files.

Answer (score 0):

Export all artboards as a single multi-page PDF.

Then use **Adobe Acrobat** to extract pages and save them as separate files.

I can't say how much faster this may be compared to using Preview, because I don't use Preview on my Macs. I don't find Preview to be a professional-level tool. But for 24 pages, it's not that labor intensive to extract and save six times via Acrobat.

Comment: Thanks, this isn't a bad solution. The only downside is that I have to rename each file manually, despite having the artboards named in illustrator already. I'll consider it though.

Comment: It's only 6 names if you are saving 2 pages per PDF.